# Can't open a jnlp file in ubuntu with either icedtea nor javaws

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firefox, java, jnlp

Hello I need to open a jnlp file. I have openjdk version "11.0.2" and the latest icedtea plugin. When I open the file directly with icedtea I get the following message:

> fatal: initialization Error: Could not initialize application. The application has not been initialized, for more information execute javaws from the command line

So I run it from the terminal with javaws path/to/file.jnlp and I get the following response:

```
itw-rust-debug: checking deployment.log.file in: /home/estefania/.config  /icedtea-web/deployment.properties
itw-rust-debug: property not located or file inaccessible
itw-rust-debug: checking deployment.log.file in: /home/estefania/.icedtea/deployment.properties
itw-rust-debug: property not located or file inaccessible
itw-rust-debug: checking deployment.log.file in: /etc/.java/.deploy/deployment.properties
itw-rust-debug: property not located or file inaccessible
itw-rust-debug: checking deployment.log.file in: /etc/.java/deployment/deployment.properties
itw-rust-debug: property not located or file inaccessible
itw-rust-debug: checking deployment.log.stdstreams in: /home/estefania/.config/icedtea-web/deployment.properties
itw-rust-debug: property not located or file inaccessible
itw-rust-debug: checking deployment.log.stdstreams in: /home/estefania/.icedtea/deployment.properties
itw-rust-debug: property not located or file inaccessible
itw-rust-debug: checking deployment.log.stdstreams in: /etc/.java/.deploy/deployment.properties
itw-rust-debug: property not located or file inaccessible
itw-rust-debug: checking deployment.log.stdstreams in: /etc/.java/deployment/deployment.properties
itw-rust-debug: property not located or file inaccessible
itw-rust-debug: checking deployment.log.system in: /home/estefania/.config/icedtea-web/deployment.properties
itw-rust-debug: property not located or file inaccessible
itw-rust-debug: checking deployment.log.system in: /home/estefania/.icedtea/deployment.properties
itw-rust-debug: property not located or file inaccessible
itw-rust-debug: checking deployment.log.system in: /etc/.java/.deploy/deployment.properties
itw-rust-debug: property not located or file inaccessible
itw-rust-debug: checking deployment.log.system in: /etc/.java/deployment/deployment.properties
itw-rust-debug: property not located or file inaccessible
itw-rust-debug: checking deployment.user.logdir in: /home/estefania/.config/icedtea-web/deployment.properties
itw-rust-debug: property not located or file inaccessible
itw-rust-debug: checking deployment.user.logdir in: /home/estefania/.icedtea/deployment.properties
itw-rust-debug: property not located or file inaccessible
itw-rust-debug: checking deployment.user.logdir in: /etc/.java/.deploy/deployment.properties
itw-rust-debug: property not located or file inaccessible
itw-rust-debug: checking deployment.user.logdir in: /etc/.java/deployment/deployment.properties
itw-rust-debug: property not located or file inaccessible
/usr/lib/icedtea-web/bin/javaws
itw-rust-debug: trying jdk over properties (deployment.jre.dir)
itw-rust-debug: checking deployment.jre.dir in: /home/estefania/.config/icedtea-web/deployment.properties
itw-rust-debug: property not located or file inaccessible
itw-rust-debug: checking deployment.jre.dir in: /home/estefania/.icedtea/deployment.properties
itw-rust-debug: property not located or file inaccessible
itw-rust-debug: checking deployment.jre.dir in: /etc/.java/.deploy/deployment.properties
itw-rust-debug: property not located or file inaccessible
itw-rust-debug: checking deployment.jre.dir in: /etc/.java/deployment/deployment.properties
itw-rust-debug: property not located or file inaccessible
itw-rust-debug: nothing
itw-rust-debug: trying jdk JAVA_HOME
itw-rust-debug: nothing
itw-rust-debug: trying jdk from registry
itw-rust-debug: nothing
itw-rust-debug: trying jdk from path
itw-rust-debug: skipping jdk from path, your build is distribution
itw-rust-debug: nothing
itw-rust-debug: failing down to hardcoded
selected jre: /usr/lib/jvm/default-java
/usr/share/icedtea-web/javaws.jar
/usr/share/java/js.jar
/usr/share/java/tagsoup.jar
itw-rust-debug: checking deployment.launcher.rust.bootcp.remove in: /home/estefania/.config/icedtea-web/deployment.properties
itw-rust-debug: property not located or file inaccessible
itw-rust-debug: checking deployment.launcher.rust.bootcp.remove in: /home/estefania/.icedtea/deployment.properties
itw-rust-debug: property not located or file inaccessible
itw-rust-debug: checking deployment.launcher.rust.bootcp.remove in: /etc/.java/.deploy/deployment.properties
itw-rust-debug: property not located or file inaccessible
itw-rust-debug: checking deployment.launcher.rust.bootcp.remove in: /etc/.java/deployment/deployment.properties
itw-rust-debug: property not located or file inaccessible
itw-rust-debug: checking deployment.launcher.rust.bootcp.add in: /home/estefania/.config/icedtea-web/deployment.properties
itw-rust-debug: property not located or file inaccessible
itw-rust-debug: checking deployment.launcher.rust.bootcp.add in: /home/estefania/.icedtea/deployment.properties
itw-rust-debug: property not located or file inaccessible
itw-rust-debug: checking deployment.launcher.rust.bootcp.add in: /etc/.java/.deploy/deployment.properties
itw-rust-debug: property not located or file inaccessible
itw-rust-debug: checking deployment.launcher.rust.bootcp.add in: /etc/.java/deployment/deployment.properties
itw-rust-debug: property not located or file inaccessible
itw-rust-debug: checking deployment.launcher.rust.cp.remove in: /home/estefania/.config/icedtea-web/deployment.properties
itw-rust-debug: property not located or file inaccessible
itw-rust-debug: checking deployment.launcher.rust.cp.remove in: /home/estefania/.icedtea/deployment.properties
itw-rust-debug: property not located or file inaccessible
itw-rust-debug: checking deployment.launcher.rust.cp.remove in: /etc/.java/.deploy/deployment.properties
itw-rust-debug: property not located or file inaccessible
itw-rust-debug: checking deployment.launcher.rust.cp.remove in: /etc/.java/deployment/deployment.properties
itw-rust-debug: property not located or file inaccessible
itw-rust-debug: checking deployment.launcher.rust.cp.add in: /home/estefania/.config/icedtea-web/deployment.properties
itw-rust-debug: property not located or file inaccessible
itw-rust-debug: checking deployment.launcher.rust.cp.add in: /home/estefania/.icedtea/deployment.properties
itw-rust-debug: property not located or file inaccessible
itw-rust-debug: checking deployment.launcher.rust.cp.add in: /etc/.java/.deploy/deployment.properties
itw-rust-debug: property not located or file inaccessible
itw-rust-debug: checking deployment.launcher.rust.cp.add in: /etc/.java/deployment/deployment.properties
itw-rust-debug: property not located or file inaccessible
itw-rust-debug: exemplar boot classpath: -Xbootclasspath/a:/usr/share/icedtea-web/javaws.jar:/usr/share/java/js.jar:/usr/share/java/tagsoup.jar
itw-rust-debug: used boot classpath: -Xbootclasspath/a:/usr/share/icedtea-web/javaws.jar:/usr/share/java/js.jar:/usr/share/java/tagsoup.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:
itw-rust-debug: used classpath: /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/lib/rt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:
itw-rust-debug: expected name: javaws
itw-rust-debug: current name: javaws
itw-rust-debug: installed bin: /usr/lib/icedtea-web/bin/javaws
itw-rust-debug: current bin: /usr/lib/icedtea-web/bin/javaws
/usr/share/icedtea-web/javaws_splash.png
itw-rust-debug: command "/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/java" "-version"
itw-rust-debug: detected jdk 9 or up
itw-rust-debug: modular jdk
/usr/lib/icedtea-web/bin/itw-modularjdk.args
itw-rust-debug: command "/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/java" "-splash:/usr/share/icedtea-web/javaws_splash.png" "@/usr/lib/icedtea-web/bin/itw-modularjdk.args" "-Xbootclasspath/a:/usr/share/icedtea-web/javaws.jar:/usr/share/java/js.jar:/usr/share/java/tagsoup.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:" "-classpath" "/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/lib/rt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:" "-Dicedtea-web.bin.name=javaws" "-Dicedtea-web.bin.location=/usr/lib/icedtea-web/bin/javaws" "net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.Boot" "/home/estefania/Documents/CONACYT" "/E-FIRMA/launch.jnlp"
WARNING: package javax.jnlp not in java.desktop
System is already following XDG .cache and .config specifications
config: /home/estefania/.config/icedtea-web file exists: true
cache: /home/estefania/.cache/icedtea-web file exists:true
Ico provider registered correctly.
Loading User level properties from: file:/home/estefania/.config/icedtea-web/deployment.properties
WARNING: key deployment.system.cachedir has no value, setting to default value
WARNING: key deployment.system.cachedir has no value, skipping
Forcing of offline set to: false
Gtk-Message: 06:41:13.843: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Starting security dialog thread
Using firefox's profiles file: /home/estefania/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini
Found preferences file: /home/estefania/.mozilla/firefox/f8iouxrj.default/prefs.js
Read 163 entries from Firefox's preferences
Proceeding with jnlp
net.sourceforge.jnlp.util.optionparser.InvalidArgumentException: [/home/estefania/Documents/CONACYT, /E-FIRMA/launch.jnlp]
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.Boot.getMainFile(Boot.java:332)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.Boot.getFileLocation(Boot.java:291)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JnlpBoot.run(JnlpBoot.java:67)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.Boot.run(Boot.java:270)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.Boot.run(Boot.java:63)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.Boot.main(Boot.java:210)

netx: Invalid argument: net.sourceforge.jnlp.util.optionparser.InvalidArgumentException: [/home/estefania/Documents/CONACYT, /E-FIRMA/launch.jnlp]
System logger called with result of 0
System logger called with result of 0
System logger called with result of 0
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?